# Error Call to a member function whereBetween() on string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando sumar la cantidad de la tabla abono en fechas especificas seleccionada por el usuario desde la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el detalle del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla Abonos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vista para seleccionar las fechas `reportes.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>
            Reporte
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'reporte/fechas', 'method'=>'GET','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
        <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-center" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Fecha inicial: </label>
                <input class="form-control "  type="date" name="fecha_ini" />
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Fecha final: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fecha_fin" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="buscar">Buscar</button>
        
            <a href="frm_total_monto.php" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Total prestamos</a>
        {!!Form::close()!!}

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Controlador, aqui es donde esta fallando `ReportesController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Abono;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ReportesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('cuentas.reporte.reportes');
    }
    public function totalAbonosmes(Request $request)
    {

        $reporte = Abono::sum('cantidad')->whereBetween('fecha', [
            Carbon::parse($request->fecha_ini)->toDateString(),
            Carbon::parse($request->fecha_fin)->toDateString(),
        ])->get();

 
        return view('cuentas.reporte.fechas', ["reporte" => $reporte]);

    }

}
```

el modelo `Abono.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Abono extends Model
{   
    protected $table='abonos';
    protected $primaryKey='idabono';

    public $timestamps=false;

        //campos que se pueden modificar
        protected $fillable=[
            'fecha',
            'observacion',
            'cuenta_id',
            'saldo_abono',
            'no_cuota',
            'cantidad'
        ];

        //campos donde no se pueden modificar
    protected $guarded=[

    ];

}
```

por ultimo las rutas `web.php`

```
Route::get('reporte', function () {
    return view('cuentas.reporte.reportes');
});

Route::get('reporte/fechas', 'ReportesController@totalAbonosmes');
```

Comment: Intenta hacerlo sin en toDateString ya que creo que por eso te salta el error de beetween en string, intentalo de esta manera, reporte = Abono::sum('cantidad')->whereBetween('fecha', [
            Carbon::parse($request->fecha_ini),
            Carbon::parse($request->fecha_fin),
        ])->get();

Comment: @FelipeUrcia ya lo habia colocado asi y no funciono.

Comment: $request->fecha_ini, podrias colocar como te trae este request porfavor

Comment: me trae los valores de esta forma: "2020-09-18"

Comment: has intentado colocar en tu modelo Abono protected $dates = ['fecha'];

Comment: por favor mira la pregunta, ahi agrege el modelo

Comment: por eso te menciono, tu estas colocandolo dentro de fillable, colocalo a parte en  protected $fillable=[
            'observacion',
            'cuenta_id',
            'saldo_abono',
            'no_cuota',
            'cantidad'
        ]; protected $dates = ['fecha'];

Comment: Ya lo agrege pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar funciones tales como [`avg` o `sum`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) retornan un valor escalar en lugar de una instancia del modelo en cuestión, es decir cualquiera de ellas así como las aplicas solo retornan el número que producto de la operación se obtuvo, entonces dado eso considero puedes reorganizarla de este modo:

Para que solo traigas el valor numérico y no estés solicitando una colección como al momento lo intentas

```
$reporte = Abono::whereBetween('fecha', [
            Carbon::parse($request->fecha_ini)->toDateString(),
            Carbon::parse($request->fecha_fin)->toDateString(),
        ])->sum('cantidad');
```

Ahora si tratas de obtener la sumatoria podrías pensar también en reorganizar la consulta de esta forma:

```
$reporte = Abono::selectRaw('SUM(cantidad) AS Cantidad')
                    ->whereBetween('fecha', [
                        Carbon::parse($request->fecha_ini)->toDateString(),
                        Carbon::parse($request->fecha_fin)->toDateString(),
        ])->first();
```

Ya que si no estamos agrupando, entonces la consulta solo devolverá un registro por lo tanto es innecesario obtener una colección y en todo caso mejor un objeto.

De esa puedes traer a impresión el valor de esta forma:

```
{{ $reporte->Cantidad }}
```